# How to get text of element but excluding a child of that element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML snippet:

```
<li class="as-selection-item">
<a class="as-close">×</a>
Rudy Hamilton
</li>
```

How can I get the value `Rudy Hamilton` from `li.as-selection-item` but without getting the value `x` from within `a.as-close`?

Comment: In what language ? JavaScript ? C ? Smalltalk V ?

Comment: this's HTML language. I want to get by jQuery or javacript is OK

Comment: $($(".as-selection-item").contents()[2]).text()

Comment: In HTML language you won't do this)

Comment: HTML is a language for structuring content - you don't do actions like "get value" with HTML - i assume you want JavaScript ?

Comment: How do you want to get this value? once selected? by calling a javascript function? ... how? when?

Comment: For this particular example, Florian's answer is sufficient; If you want to go generalize, walk through the first level DOM tree under `.as-selection-item` and get all node that has `nodeType==3`.

Answer (score 10):

### Solution 1

```
document.querySelector('.as-close').nextSibling.nodeValue
```

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t8Qst/

It uses `nextSibling` to get the node right after the element with the `as-close` class.

### Solution 2

If you want to get everything inside the li, except the anchor, you can use this:

```
var li = document.querySelector('.as-selection-item').cloneNode(true);
li.removeChild(li.querySelector('.as-close'));
alert(li.textContent);
```

You clone the li, remove the anchor from the clone, and just display its text.

JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/58pLz/

With jQuery (in case you're already using it), this'd give this:

```
var li = $('.as-selection-item').clone();
$('.as-close', li).remove();
alert(li.text());
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to exclude one node rather than just selecting only one.

Comment: In case OP means the more general "first level text": http://jsfiddle.net/t8Qst/1/

Comment: @Florian Margaine : I have a question: Is it possible to pass all jQuery selector strings to the function 'document.querySelector' ?

Comment: @ABFORCE no, only CSS selectors. jQuery and CSS selectors differ in some ways, so you have to be careful.

Comment: @ABFORCE a last note: `querySelector` returns the 1st element that matches the selector. If you want to get all the elements, use `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can use this:

```
$(".as-selection-item").text();
```

This will return all the thext inside `.as-selection-item` and not the html

If you only want the text inside .as-selection-item (not in the anchor) you can use this:

```
$(".as-selection-item").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

This clonese the object, removes the children, and returns the text.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D559Y/)

Comment: But... there is some text in the anchor.